# Are there any suitable catalysts for ferric oxide and aluminum reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, catalysis

As an exercise, I am trying to figure out how to catalyze the reaction of ferric oxide and aluminum

Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> + 2Al -> 2Fe + Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>

I've been trying to find a substance A such that the reaction could be broken down into the steps:

Fe<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> + A -> B + 2Fe

B + 2Al -> Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> + A

And ΔG<sub>rxn</sub> for the first step is much less than that for the original reaction. I've had quite a bit of trouble finding online resources to assist me in my search. In general, are there any better methods for determining a suitable catalyst for such redox reactions? (education level high school junior, AP chem student).

Comment: They don't need a catalyst. Once ignited, they react all by themselves, and quite fiercely.

Comment: @IvanNeretin It still doesn't proceed very quickly though. Experimentally, a lot of the heat energy would be absorbed in subsequent reactions, not to mention by the iron itself. Is there any other way to lower the reaction's activation energy?